# 'require' was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm starting to study Node.js. I purchased the manual written by Marc Wandscheider.
I downloaded the tools to use it and I also downloaded Brackets.

I'm trying a sample script, but I get two errors that do not understand and that are not present in the guide.

The first error tells me that:

> 'require' was used before it was defined

```
C:\node> node debug web.js
<Debugger listening on port 5858>
connecting ... ok
break in C:\node\web.js: 1
   1 var http = require ("http");
   2
   3 process_request function (req, res) {
debug>
```

while the second (in Brackets):

> missing use strict statement

I saw on the internet that I can add the line

```
"use strict";
```

But the guide does not use it - is it required?

How can I fix these issues?

entire code

```
var http = require("http");

function process_request(req, res) {

    var body = 'Thanks for calling!';
    var content_length = body.length;
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Length': content_length,
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
    res.end(body);
}

var s = http.createServer(process_request);
s.listen(8080);
```

Comment: It usually means that something else is blowing up. You should show the actual code. Anywhom, shouldn't `process_request function (req, res)` be `var process_request = function (req, res)` or `function process_request(req, res)` ?

Comment: Check your package.json and try installing the required modules first using npm install command

Comment: I believe I have resolved

I run the command

npm npm install -g

I found a mistake in the first run
Error: ENOENT, stat 'C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Roaming\npm'

it was enough to create the folder specified in the ritch

and relaunch

npm npm install -g

it all seems ok though
it happens sometimes happens that comes out this error message

<code> 
C:\node>node debug web.js
< debugger listening on port 5858
connecting... ok
break in timers.js:77
  75 }
  76
  77 function listOnTimeout() {
  78   var msecs = this.msecs;
  79   var list = this;



<code>

Comment: I do not know why though brackets
still gives me these errors debugging

  JSLint Problems
×
1 'require' was used before it was defined. var http = require ("http");
5 Missing 'use strict' statement. var body = 'Thanks for calling!';
6 Combine this with the previous 'var' statement. var = CONTENT_LENGTH body.length;
7 Expected 'res' at column 5, not column 9. res.writeHead (200, {
10 Expected '}' at column 5, not column 9.});
11 Expected 'res' at column 5, not column 9. res.end (body);

Answer (score 6):

Those errors are actually suggestions of the JSHINT process to validate good code. Brackets is using it behind the scene probably. 
If you tell jshint you are writing for node then **require** becomes a global variable so it does not give that error.
Try running this code with some warnings for [JSHINT](http://jshint.com/) some article with proper explanation [on using JSHINT](https://coderwall.com/p/-h1h1w/how-to-use-jslint-in-node-js-projects-properly)

```
/*jshint node:true */
'use strict';
var http = require('http');

function process_request(req, res) {

    var body = 'Thanks for calling!';
    var content_length = body.length;
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Length': content_length,
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
    res.end(body);
}

var s = http.createServer(process_request);
s.listen(8080);
```

Comment: To fix this for me, I had to use jslint instead of jshint.

Comment: Use `/*jslint node:true */` in case of JSLint as pointed above by @Brideau

Answer (score 2):

I encountered similar warnings from the JSLint window in Brackets while writing a gulp file. This is how I resolved them:

`Problems × 1 'require' was used before it was defined.`

The require function is defined elsewhere, specifically as part of Node.js so to resolve the warning, mark it as a global by adding this at the top of your JavaScript file:

```
/* global require */
```

See http://jslinterrors.com/a-was-used-before-it-was-defined

`Missing 'use strict' statement`

I resolved this by using an immediately invoked function expression:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The rest of the code
}());
```

See http://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function

`Combine this with the previous 'var' statement`

This one is straightforward. Instead of

```
var body = 'Thanks for calling!';
var content_length = body.length;
```

use

```
var body = 'Thanks for calling!',
    content_length = body.length;
```